# Error bars for skyline plot?

Tags: r

I have made a consensus tree (in newick format) and rebranched it using functions from the ape package.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add error bars to the skyline plot?

Cheers!
Input:

```
>write.tree(ccc)
[1] "(13.1,43.1,28.1,21.1,20.1,4.1,37.1,23.1,29.1,15.1,36.1,40.1,26.1,16.1,33.1,10.1,18.1,6.1,11.1,34.1,2.1,38.1,35.1,8.1,42.1,22.1,5.1,27.1,39.1,17.1,30.1,31.1,41.1,7.1,25.1,3.1,12.1,14.1,1.1,24.1,9.1,32.1,19.1);"
```

Branched tree and final input:

```
> write.tree(new_tree)
[1] "   (13.1:1.244090638,43.1:0.1755118382,28.1:4.442071925,21.1:4.866247957,20.1:3.863557777,4.1:0.08206463186,37.1:1.180065627,23.1:4.778251834,29.1:4.65377018,15.1:3.726316827,36.1:3.799621998,40.1:1.707243007,26.1:3.655532246,16.1:2.436848865,33.1:1.315581813,10.1:0.5973169219,18.1:2.561718575,6.1:1.409437305,11.1:4.000977813,34.1:2.769218051,2.1:1.143412833,38.1:2.636477078,35.1:3.435094416,8.1:0.3714309109,42.1:4.429772993,22.1:0.2805716533,5.1:2.991251546,27.1:3.269689628,39.1:1.192241808,17.1:1.866855259,30.1:1.363407132,31.1:3.150236446,41.1:4.079005712,7.1:2.695786237,25.1:2.867184281,3.1:3.351797838,12.1:1.958669939,14.1:3.119812493,1.1:4.864444738,24.1:1.734493783,9.1:3.283970281,32.1:3.055829309,19.1:0.8193949074);"

require(ape)
new_tree<-compute.brlen(ccc,runif,min=0,max=5)
sk1 <- skyline(new_tree)   
sk2 <- skyline(new_tree, 0.0119) 
plot(sk1, show.years=TRUE, subst.rate=0.0023, present.year = 2011, col="red")
lines(sk2,  show.years=TRUE, subst.rate=0.0023, present.year = 2011)
legend(.15,500, c("classic", "generalized"), col="red",lty=1)
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? We don't have access to the `ccc` object. Also, specify which packages you're using.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik - I have added the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plotCI` from package `plotrix`. Would be fun to append the `plot.skyline` tree to implement error bars...

Anyway, this is the code I used to produce the below picture. I used a different data set that comes with the `ape` package. You'll have to take care of the details.

```
library(ape)
library(plotrix)
data(bird.orders)

new_tree <- compute.brlen(bird.orders, runif, min = 0, max = 5)
sk1 <- skyline(new_tree)   

subst.rate <- 0.0023
year <- 2011
m <- sk1$population.size
lm <- length(m)

plot(sk1, show.years=TRUE, subst.rate = subst.rate, present.year = year, col="red")

plotCI(x = (-c(0, sk1$time))/subst.rate + year, y = c(m, m[lm]),
        uiw = runif(length(sk1$time)+1, min = 1, max = 30), # some random deviation
        #liw = runif(length(sk1$time)+1, min = 1, max = 30), # this one can be missing, see ?plotCI
        add = TRUE,
        pt.bg = NA
)

legend(.15,500, c("classic", "generalized"), col="red",lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this exactly what I was looking for! Greetings!

Comment: Whoops, my bad. The other package is `plotrix`, not `Hmisc`. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I figured :-). I used it with plotrix.